# Problem with "create_infotables()" function in "Information" package

Tags: r

I want to calculate Information Value (IV) and WoE using Information package in r. I am using following code -

```
library(Information)
df_iv <- df
IV <- create_infotables(data=df_iv[, -1], 
                    y = "stroke", 
                    bins=10)
```

initially my dependent variable was a factor and I got following error-

```
Error in CheckInputs(data, valid, trt, y) : 
ERROR: the dependent variable stroke is a factor in training dataset -- has to be numeric
```

Then I changed the dependent variable to numeric as follows-

```
library(Information)
df_iv <- df
df_iv$stroke <- as.numeric(df_iv$stroke)
IV <- create_infotables(data=df_iv[, -1], 
                    y = "stroke", 
                    bins=10)
```

Now I am getting following error-

```
Error in CheckInputs(data, valid, trt, y) : 
ERROR: the dependent variable has to be binary. Check your training and validation datasets.
```

My dependent variable has only two values "0" and "1".
Why is the happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a factor to a numeric will by default convert the factor levels to integers starting at 1 - so if your dependent was originally 0/1 it will end up as 1/2 which will throw the error.

A simple fix is to just subtract 1 from the value of your numeric variable.

E.g.

```
library(Information)

# succeeds, 0/1 by default
create_infotables(data= mtcars,y='vs')

# fails, now 1/2 numeric
mtcars$vs_converted <- as.numeric(as.factor(mtcars$vs))
create_infotables(data= mtcars,y='vs_converted')

# succeeds, now 0/1 binary
mtcars$vs_converted <- as.numeric(as.factor(mtcars$vs))-1
create_infotables(data= mtcars,y='vs_converted')
```